# JS: Error: Could not load CSS from app.css: Error: require's first parameter should be string

Tags: vuejs2, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have encountered this problem when serving my NATIVESCRIPT-VUE APP on my android device.
[image]

Btw, this is a code-sharing approach(Web and Mobile). I didn't create any custom code yet, I just run the template code.
I don't see any app.css in the code base and I think this is a generated file created by the webpack.

This projects runs on VUE2 and nativescript version 6

Answer (score 0):

Try and execute this :
`npm i -g @nativescript/schematics@latest`
and run it again

if that didn't work i believe its testing issue , you can `test --igonre`